# Httparty request to curl

Tags: ruby, curl, httparty

Is there a way to convert an httparty request to a curl request?  I would love to be able to send another developer my failed request in a curl format.

I was thinking something like this:

```
web_caller = HTTPartyClass.new
web_caller.hit_api
web_caller.last_request_as_curl
```

Where last_request_as_curl would turn the previous request into a curl string that I can give to the owner of the API when debugging.

Ideally, `last_request_as_curl` would return something like: "curl -X POST ....."

Comment: Can you show the bit of code that makes the request you want to explicit ?

Comment: The original question was pretty open-ended.  I updated the question with some precisions and added my solution.  If someone has come across a better one, our there is an existing solution please share.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a method in my HTTParty base class:

```
def capture_curl(request)
  options = request.options
  method  = request.http_method.to_s.split(':').last.upcase
  curl_str =  "curl -k -X #{method} "
  if(options[:basic_auth].present?)
    curl_str += "-u #{options[:basic_auth].values.join(':')} "
  end
  curl_str +=
    "-d " +
    options[:body]
      .merge(options[:default_params])
      .map{|a,k| "#{a}=#{k}"}
      .join('&') + " "
  curl_str += "#{options[:base_uri]}#{request.path.path}"
  @curl_str = curl_str
end

def last_curl
  @curl_str
end
```

I have a method that always handles the response object and in that method I pass the `response.request` to `capture_curl`.

Comment: unfortunately errors out with "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass in .merge(options[:default_params])". httparty (0.21.0)